# delphi return array of integer from a COM object function

Tags: c#, delphi, object, delphi-2010, pascal

A typelibrary is created from C # and used that to in Delphi 5.

there is a method in type library that is returning a array or string. In Delphi same array of string I have to get but when I compiled the code following error is comming.

```
Incompatible types: 'tagSAFEARRAY' and 'Array'
```

Here is C # code

```
    public int[] sqrRootUpto(int num)
    {
        int[] result={0};
        int tempVal=0;
        for (int i = 2; num < tempVal; i++)
        {
            tempVal = i * i;
            result[i] = tempVal;                
      }
        return result;

    }
```

Here is Delphi code Where I am calling those above function.

```
    procedure TForm1.BtnSqrtClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  num :Integer;
  result : array of Integer;
begin
      num := StrToInt(EditSqrtInput.text);
      result := newObj.sqrRootUpto(num);   //Here I am calling the above method
end; 
end.
```

**EDIT**

```
var
result : variant;

begin
 result := VarArrayCreate([0, 20], varInteger);

Error!! Incompatible types: 'tagSAFEARRAY' and 'Array'
```

TBL.pas having this signature for the function

```
function  TMathClass.sqrRootUpto(rNum: Integer): PSafeArray;
begin
  Result := DefaultInterface.sqrRootUpto(rNum);
end;
```

what is diff b/w TSafeArray and TSafeArray

Comment: I think the first step would be to look into the definition of tadSAFEARRAY, TSafeArray etc. which I think exist in ActiveX.pas. These are meant to be used with Variant arrays I believe. I also presume your real example is more complex because this would be trivial to code in Delphi.

Comment: I used aavriant array also but not able go get that.

Comment: what is diff b/w TSafeArray and TSafeArray ? I think you meaned TSafeArray and PSafeArray. PSafeArray is a pointer to TSafeArray structure.

Comment: it's no use you trying to allocate the TSafeArray since that is returned from the C# code.  It would be much easier just to allocate a dynamic array of integers and pass this into the C# routine by reference and marshall it that way.  Since you know how big the array needs to be this is perfectly possible with little change.

Answer (score 0):

There is already TSafeArray record defined in ActiveX.pas. Maybe this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

try declaring

```
var
  result: TIntegerDynArray;
```

Edit: After your edit, it's clear that your COM method returns a `PSafeArray`. An easiest way to use an array of Integer would be to convert it to a variant array first:

```
function IntSafeArrayToVarArray(const P: PSafeArray): OleVariant;
begin
  if Assigned(P) then
  begin
    VarClear(Result);
    tagVariant(Result).vt := varInteger or varArray;
    tagVariant(Result).PArray := P;
  end
  else
    Result := Null;
end;
```

You can then use this function because variant array of integers is assignment-compatible with a `TIntegerDynArray`:

```
result := IntSafeArrayToVarArray(newObj.sqrRootUpto(num));
for I := Low(result) to High(Result) do ...
```

Comment: Why would that help? TIntegerDynArray is declared as array of Integer.

Comment: nonsense, the function should IMHO return TSafeArray if the compiler rejected with tagSAFEARRAY incompatibility error.